# Conditionally return or break a switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, return, break

I am refactoring a switch statement in which I am performing am `if` conditional within one of the cases where the `if` will `break` the switch case and the `else` will `return`.

Is it possible to perform this as a quicker conditional such as a Ternary or something else, rather than a standard if/else?

**Original**

```
let someCondition;

// someCondition is set at some point

switch(toSwitchOn) {
    case myCase:
        if (someCondition) {
           sendObj({someKey: 'someVal', condition: true});
           break;
        } else {
           sendObj({condition: false});
           return false;           
        }
}
```

**Refactored so far**

```
let someCondition;

// someCondition is set at some point

switch(toSwitchOn) {
    case myCase:
        sendObj({
           ...!!someCondition && {someKey: 'someVal'},
           condition: !!someCondition
        });
     
        if (someCondition) { break; } else {return false}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of a `switch` with just one `case`? That should just be `if`.

Comment: There's no extra points for creating more terse code if it becomes more confusing. The original code is much more readable than the refactored version.

Comment: What @Barmar said (re `switch` with one `case`). But also: What's wrong with the first version? It's clear, easy to read, easy to debug, ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "performing" means to you, but your code should be clear and easy to read, as other people have already answered in the comments.

You can take a look at these topics: [Definition of 'clean code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954570/definition-of-clean-code)
and [To ternary or not to ternary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160295/7186622)

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
let someCondition;

// someCondition is set at some point

switch(true) {
    case someCondition:
         sendObj({someKey: 'someVal', condition: true});
         break;
    default:
         sendObj({condition: false});
         return false;           
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
let someCondition

// someCondition is set at some point

switch (toSwitchOn) {
    case myCase: {
        const result = handleCondition()
        if (result) break
        else return false
    }
}
function handleCondition() {
    let obj, result
    if (someCondition) {
        obj = { someKey: "someVal", condition: true } 
        result = true
    } else {
        obj = { condition: false }
        result = false
    }
    sendObj(obj)
    return result
}
```